# I need to know how and why catia is crashing while working with windchill on winxp

Tags: windows-xp

I am working in a production environment on a Catia application and windchill workgroup manager client 9.1 with Windows XP SP2 on an HP XW9400 workstation with 4GB RAM and NVIDIA Quadro FX 4600 graphic card.

My problem is while working with windchill and Catia, Catia is crashing when I am rotating or moving a product or part. Because of this a lot of users were losing their unsaved data.

So I want to know why Catia is crashing and and what is the solution.

I installed NVIDIA drivers 182.65 version. This was recommended by Dassault Systems.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried submitting this to PTC tech support, they should able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I recall Dassault provides support if the user is using an approved video card and driver. From a Google search: https://www.nvidia.com/object/dassault_certified_drivers.html